# Closing a Specific Terminal

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal

I have a program that opens a new terminal and runs while loop, but when the program ends I want to terminate this window.  Is it possible to close a certain terminal window with a command, while keeping all other terminals open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Njap

The easy way: Create a variable that the while loop tests for true (or false, whatever way you like) and change this var to end the loop.

The complicated way:
Get the Pid of you Shell:

```
$ echo $$
```

returns e.g.

```
1441
```

The Shell (e.g. bash) runs in the Terminal, so the Terminal is identified by bashs parent PID. Get ppid:

```
$ cat /proc/1441/status | grep PPid
```

returns e.g.

```
1432
```

If you can Pid it, you can kill it. ;)

```
$ kill 1432
```

EDIT: There might be easier ways to get the Pid of the program process, e.g. if the program has a specific name, you can

$  ps aux | grep nameofmyspecificprogram

for it.

Comment: Use `pgrep` and `pkill`. And use code formatting.